# ANOVA results reject null hypothesis for all samples, is it normal?

Tags: anova, matlab

I have done ANOVA analysis of the experimental test data on Matlab. The test data is about the flexural strength of products made from different mixes. Within each design mix, only one of the ingredient's quantity was varied to study the effects. The ANOVA result shows all of the mixes have lower P values than the significant level (0.05) and higher F values than corresponding F-critical values. Both these results rejects the null hypothesis. Since all the mixes have the same outcome, therefore, I am interested in further exploring how can I statistically show which mix had higher impact on improving the flexural properties? Is it possible to get the percentage contribution or any such thing to further examine and prove the contribution.